# How to find to "opposite" records on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, subquery

I have 1 table with the following cols:

```
giver_id | receiver_id
   10    |     12
    9    |     10
   10    |     20
   12    |     10
```

I am looking for a mysql query that will return `10-12` / `12-10` as a match.

Thanks

Comment: You can use join with multiple conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To identify the records for which an "opposite" record exist, you could do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM mytable t1 
    WHERE t1.giver_id = t.receiver_id AND t.giver_id = t1.receiver_id 
)
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rMHu9bQYSSokhusXU8dQmC/0)** with your sample data returns:

```
| giver_id | receiver_id |
| -------- | ----------- |
| 10       | 12          |
| 12       | 10          |
```